# Setting local chunk options for a specific chunk in knitr?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, chunks

I'm using `knitr` to knit RMarkdown, and there have been multiple times where I have wanted to add code chunks programmatically, but failed to find a way to do so satisfactorily. Say I want to have `knitr` play a sound when a file has finished knitting.  My way around this problem has been like so:

```r
beep_on_knit <- function(beep_sound=3, sleep=3) {
  library(beepr)
  last_label <- tail(knitr::all_labels(),n=1)[[1]]
  knitr::knit_hooks$set(
    .beep_on_last_chunk =
      function(before, options) {
        if (options$label == last_label & !before) {
          beepr::beep(beep_sound)
          Sys.sleep(sleep)
          invisible(NULL)
        }
      })
  # Sets the options for every chunk so the hook will be run on them
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(.beep_on_last_chunk = TRUE)
}
```

However, having to edit the chunk properties of every single chunk (i.e., `knitr::opts_chunk$set(.beep_on_last_chunk = TRUE)` means that if I add this function to a document, it invalidates the cache of every previously cached chunk.

Is there a way to set the options of a specific chunk beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to set `knitr::opts_chunk$set(.beep_on_last_chunk = TRUE)` globally for the document. Is it possible for you to set `.beep_on_last_chunk = TRUE` only on the last chunk as a local chunk option? If this is possible, you won't need to test `if (options$label == last_label)` in the hook.

Alternatively, you may consider using the `document` hook, which is executed after the whole document has been knitted, e.g.,

```r
knitr::knit_hooks$set(document = function(x) {
  beepr::beep(3)
  x
})
```

Comment: I just set `.beep_on_last_chunk` globally so that the custom hook I made would run (and check) every chunk.  Using a local option in the last chunk would make it "work", but I'd like to come up with a solution that works automatically.  Otherwise, I could just put the beep function in the last chunk myself anyway.
I actually did end up using the document hook for this problem (because if the last chunk is cached, the above hook would never check it), but I'd still love the option to better programmatically manipulate chunks.
Thanks!